# Simplifying the Boolean expression $x'y + x(x+y')$

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, boolean

**Expression:**

$$x'y + x(x+y')$$

**My attempt:**

1. $x'y + x(x+y')$
2. $x'y + xx + xy' \quad \textit{After applying second Distributive law.}$
3. $x'y + x + xy' \quad \textit{After applying second Idempotent law.}$
4. $x'y + x(1 + y') \quad \textit{Breaking out x}$
5. $x'y + x(1) \quad \textit{After applying Annihilation law}$
6. $x'y + x$

The answer is: $x + y$.

N.B. I am still new to this and learning, I am using the following book:

```
Discrete Mathematics for Computing / Edition 3
by Peter Grossman
```

Comment: @amrsa, I reverted back to my original writing. Now I am stuck with $x'y + x$

Comment: @amrsa I got that from the **Bing Copilot**.

Comment: @amrsa which law did you apply here?

Comment: @amrsa the final answer in this book is `x + y` not sure what you are suggesting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For short, I'll abbreviate below Absorption, Associativity, Commutativity, Distributivity and Idempotence as abs, assoc, comm, distr and idemp, respectively.

> **Lemma.** In a Boolean algebra, if $a+b=ab$, then $a=b$.
>
> *Proof.* If $a+b = ab$ then
> \begin{align}
> a 
> &= a (a + b)   \tag{abs}\\
> &= a (ab)      \tag{hypothesis}\\
> &= ab          \tag{assoc, idemp}\\
> &= b (ab)      \tag{assoc, comm, idemp}\\
> &= b (a + b)   \tag{hypothesis}\\
> &= b.          \tag{abs}
> \end{align}

Now,
\begin{align}
(x + x'y) + (x + y)
&= x + y + x'y    \tag{assoc, comm, idemp}\\
&= x + (y + x'y)  \tag{assoc}\\
&= x + y,         \tag{abs}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
(x + x'y)(x+y)
&= x + xy + x'yx + x'y \tag{distr}\\
&= x + (xy + x'y)      \tag{assoc, $xx'=0$}\\
&= x + (x + x')y       \tag{distr}\\
&= x + y.              \tag{$x + x' = 1$}
\end{align}

Hence, letting $a = x + x'y$ and $b = x + y$, we have $a + b = b = ab$, and so $a=b$, by the Lemma.
So $x + x'y = x + y$.

---

Shorter version:
\begin{align}
x + x'y 
&= (x + xy) + x'y \tag{abs}\\
&= x + (xy + x'y) \tag{assoc}\\
&= x + (x + x')y  \tag{distr}\\
&= x + y.
\end{align}
According to a deleted answer below, this law is called *Redundancy law*.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest Solution

You can use venn diagram to solve
create it
use 2 different circles for x and y

x'y=y\x
x(x+y')=x

sum of both=x+y

That is why

Comment: `Discrete Mathematics for Computing / Edition 3
by Peter Grossman` I am using this book, this problem is in the book on page 164 and it requires the usage of the boolean laws of algebra och the various laws for simplification to be used. Not Venn Diagrams from the Sets chapter much earlier.